# Click on marker in Google Maps for Android click makes directions/maps buttons disappear

Tags: c#, xamarin, google-maps-android-api-2

My Xamarin Android app uses Google Maps API. I have thousands of markers to place on a map, so in order to do that efficiently I have implemented the `OnCameraIdle` method in which I add to the map only markers within the visible region:

```
public void OnCameraIdle()
{
   var bounds = googleMap.Projection.VisibleRegion.LatLngBounds;
   googleMap.Clear();
   // add markers
}
```

When I click a marker, the camera is moved to that marker, and shows the "directions/maps slide-out buttons" (whatever it's called) in the bottom right corner. But, consequently the `OnCameraIdle` is fired and all markers are cleared, so the slide-out slides back in again (disappears).

Should I prevent the `OnCameraIdle` event to occur in this case? I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up keeping track of the markers I added to the map, and then in `OnCameraIdle` removing each out-of-bounds-marker by using the `Remove` method on the marker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Xamarin but in native android, you can disable that behavior like this:

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> true);
```

Comment: By the way, my mMap object is probably equal to your googleMap object.